# SpecFlow is not matching Examples fields

Tags: c#, .net-core, bdd, specflow

I have a scenario:

```
Scenario: Check all these numbers
    Given I got <cat>
    When I get string <string>
    Then I see result <result>
Examples: 
    | cat | string | result |
    | 1   | a      | 1=a    |
    | 2   | b      | 2=b    |
    | 3   | c      | 3=c    |
```

And this step definition:

```
[Given(@"I got (.*)")]
public void Igot(string cat)
{
    // will do stuff here
}
```

The `cat` parameter in method `Igot()` is receiving the value `"<cat>"`, not the string value `"1"`.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SpecFlow code, replace `Scenario` with `Scenario Outline`:

```
Scenario Outline: Check all these numbers
    Given I got <cat>
    When I get string <string>
    Then I see result <result>
Examples: 
    | cat | string | result |
    | 1   | a      | 1=a    |
    | 2   | b      | 2=b    |
    | 3   | c      | 3=c    |
```

Comment: (facepalm-facepalm-facepalm)